# php mysql: not accepting unchanged form inputs

Tags: php, forms, input, form-submit

I have noticed that if I submit my form using

```
<form method="post" action="">
```

and changing at least one of the input's value it is working fine, I mean my save() function is working and saving my records to database.
However, if none of the input values are changed, else {} block is executed which is false for save().
Can anybody explain why it is so?

Comment: No we can't explain what your code does without seeing it.

Comment: Can you post in your save function so we can see what you are talking about?  There needs to be more examples in this question so we can figure out what is going on.

Comment: my save function returns return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false;   So does that mean it returns false if I send the same values to my database table ? I mean no rows get affected if same data is provided?

Comment: its because none of the rows are affected when no changes are made in the form fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be using something like

```
if($query->affected_rows()>0){
return true;
}else{
return false
}
```

After doing the database save sql query. So, when changes are made in the form fields, the changes are saved and the first condition becomes true returning true. But when no changes are made in the form field, i.e if the fields are kept intact, no changes is made to the database and the second, i.e else condition gets executed returning false.

**UPDATE**

I could be able to explain it to you more clearly if you post the code. There is nothing wrong with the html form code that you have posted. But you need to post the PHP code which is handling the save operation.

Comment: Thank you very much. As I posted on my comment above my save function returns return ($database->affected_rows() == 1) ? true : false; So you are right. I did not know that affacted rows would be 0 if no change made.

Comment: Every one bumps into such problems once, I did too. It took me days to figure it out. :) 
ENjoy programming.. and enjoy stackoverflow :)

Answer (score -2):

You can keep the old values in somewhere. When user posts the form, you can check it out if anything is changed.